# Unable to download gems during gitlab setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, bundler, gitlab

I am trying to setup gitlab for my team on a Ubuntu 14.04 system, my network is behind a proxy and hence facing hell lot of issue during the setup.

I was able to successfully complete most of the setup and struck at this particular command

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws kerberos
```

When I run above command I get the following error

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

From my understanding the above error is due to proxy.

If execute below command it works perfectly alright(my current user is `user1`)

```
$ sudo bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws kerberos
```

Also, I have set all the proxy configurations by exporting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables.

One more thing I would like to add is, if I execute the command for `user1` it again gives the same error as above

```
$ sudo -u user1 -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws kerberos
```

I could not identify where the exact problem is.

I was following the gitlab configuration from this [path](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)

Comment: Are there any reasons you are not using the omnibus setup? As written in the documentation, "Since an installation from source is a lot of work and error prone we strongly recommend the fast and reliable Omnibus package installation (deb/rpm)"

Comment: Even I tried that too, but the command `curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash` always fails.

Comment: Maybe that should be the question that you will ask in the gitlab community instead of installing it from source. Create an issue in the gitlab site, https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/issues

Comment: @Arjay I tried using the omnibus setup by downloading the deb file manually. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)

> Since an installation from source is a lot of work and error prone we
>   strongly recommend the fast and reliable Omnibus package installation
>   (deb/rpm)

If you have other issues in using **Gitlab**, create an issue at their [issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues).